# Blurred text with Firefox in Xubuntu 18 on Lenovo Legion Y540-15IRH-PG0

Tags: xubuntu, firefox, lenovo

[txt blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi7KH.png)I have trouble reading [blurred picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP6xb.png)text with Firefox in Xubuntu on a [Lenovo Y540-15IRH-PG0](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y540-15irh-pg0/documentation) laptop [drivers](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/legion-series/legion-y540-15irh-pg0), pls see text.

Is there anything I can do to remedy?

Kindly

Erika
[change0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJgNm.png)

```
erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system

(nvidia-settings:2046): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:25:05.396: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 18:25:05.398: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 18:25:05.398: PRIME: is it supported? no
erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ 

(nvidia-settings:2046): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:25:05.396: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 18:25:05.398: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 18:25:05.398: PRIME: is it supported? no
erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$
```

Comment: What  drivers do you have installed?

Comment: @user3140225 erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: This command does not show the installed drivers but the video adapters you have in your laptop. Supposing that you haven't installed the proprietary drivers: open "Software & Updates", go to the "Additional Drivers" tab, select the Nvidia driver (the one that says "proprietary, tested" in parentheses) and click apply. After that restart your laptop. You should now have the Nvidia proprietary driver installed. Check again the command `nvidia-settings`.

Comment: @user3140225 Hi I am back from vacation, sorry for the time to come back.  No drivers found there, and this is the output for CMD  erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:2570): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:32:02.251: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 15:32:02.254: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 15:32:02.254: PRIME: is it supported? no
erikajana@erikajana-Legion-Y540-15IRH-PG0:~$ 
Tx for helping.Kindly

Comment: Hi! Can you run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390 nvidia-prime`, reboot and report back?

Comment: Could you also edit your post to add a screenshot of your blurry fonts problem?

Comment: @ user3140225 Tx, did so:)

Comment: What exactly is blurred? It looks fine to me.

Comment: pls see for example orange button w white txt Add Comment

Comment: Both images you uploaded are really small and I can't see the blurring. Does another browser have the same problem?